Uneven Spacing with Consecutive Math Environments
I'm encountering a spacing issue when trying to display two mathematical equations consecutively using the \[...\] environment in LaTeX. The problem is that the vertical spacing around the equations is not symmetrical—the space above the first equation is larger than the space below the second equation.
I'd appreciate any advice or alternative approaches to fix this issue.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Here is twice the same equation, for no apparent reason:
    \[
        E = mc^2
    \]
    \[
        E = mc^2
    \]
    As you can see, the space above the first equation is slightly larger than the space below the second equation. Compare it to this:
    \[
        E = mc^2
    \]
    You see that the space below the equation is a little bit bigger here.
\end{document}



Maybe use gather(ed) or something similar instead of using several displayed formulas?

You never want consecutive display math environments.

The second display uses \abovedisplayshortskip and \belowdisplayshortskip. You can see it by adding an exaggerated setting:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{100pt}

Here is twice the same equation, for no apparent reason:
\[
E = mc^2
\]
\[
E = mc^2
\]
As you can see, the space above the first equation is slightly
larger than the space below the second equation. Compare it to this:
\[
E = mc^2
\]
You see that the space below the equation is a little bit bigger here.

\end{document}


Consecutive equations should be dealt with gather.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{100pt}

Here is twice the same equation, for no apparent reason:
\begin{gather*}
E = mc^2
\\
E = mc^2
\end{gather*}
As you can see, the space above the first equation is slightly 
larger than the space below the second equation. Compare it to this:
\[
E = mc^2
\]
You see that the space below the equation is a little bit bigger here.

\end{document}



It's a first-order error to have consecutive display-math environments. Use a suitable multi-row display-math environment instead.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
The same math expression twice in a row; the $-$ symbols denote the math axes.
\begin{align*}
        ------{} \\
        ------{}
\end{align*}
The space above the first row is the same as the space below the second row.
\end{document}


You can additionally use \intertext to have a paragraph in between math environments that are aligned with each other.

@Davislor - Thanks for this observation.
